# How two git merge and keep some diff?

Tags: git, merge

I have a config file:

in branch **master**:

```
url=http://somewhere.com
```

in branch **local**:

```
url=http://localhost:8080
```

I wanna keep all things the same, except the `url` value in the config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple.  Change the merge before you commit it.

```
git checkout local
git merge --no-commit master
(edit url, change to http://localhost:8080)
git add .
git commit
```

It's generally a bad idea to keep configuration files in the repository if there are multiple installations of the software.

Comment: It's the way I did. Any better easier way?

Comment: Seems pretty easy to me, only two extra steps compared to a regular merge.

Comment: All Content even config files should be in source control :)

Comment: @TobyAllen: Read what I wrote again.  You should not keep configuration files in the [software] repository if there are multiple installations of the software.

Comment: @DietrichEpp surely you should as that's the only way you know the proper setup for the installation.  What happens if someone wants to download and build the code, they cant because the config file is elsewhere.http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Put_Everything_Under_Version_Control

Comment: Please read more carefully the article you linked, which said "keep everything in version control".  It did not say "keep everything in the same repository", which was the point I was making.  If your software looks for the configuration file in one place, but the configuration needs to differ from installation to installation, then don't keep it in the software repository.  Put it in a separate configuration repository.  Otherwise you will have to maintain a separate branch for each computer running a given program, for example -- a potential logistical nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

Your config file should be in your .gitignore.

Comment: No, It's a plugin config file. And it will be in product.